# Sorting a character vector and removing sepators in R

Tags: r

I am working on a task for my R course. I have the following vector:

```
vector<-c("If;umbrella.;rains,;it;take;I;will;an")
```

The task is to:

1) remove the ;
2) order the vector (If it rains, I will take an umbrella.)
3) write the result to the console without the ""

I can do step 3) with just using cat(B), although I am not sure that is the correct way. Step 1) and 2) are a bit confusing - do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat(paste(strsplit(vector,";")[[1]][c(1,4,3,6,7,5,8,2)],collapse=" "))
# If it rains, I will take an umbrella.
```